# Regex required: It should contain only [alphabets] or [alphabets and digits] but not [only didgits] and not operator or special character in java

Tags: java, regex

Valid: `abc` `abc11`

Invalid: `11` `a-b` `a&&b` `a << b` `a&b` `a->b`

Comment: Why not two regexes and then `if(containsAlphabet && containsAlphanumeric)`?

Comment: @Thilo that would not satisfy his homework assignment :)

Comment: Seriously, what's the point of teachers giving homework of this type when surely they know that people will ask on forums. Are they testing student's Googling ability?

Comment: @Marko - homework exercises are designed for the benefit of those who do them, not for those who find some way not to do them.  Someone who cheats is only really cheating themselves.  ("Google it" won't work in an exam.)

Comment: @Stephen - Touche. I wish students understood this too. 60% are at University to satisfy their parents and have a 'degree'.

Answer (score 2):

One regexp:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\d]*^/
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two regexes. One that checks it's only alphanumeric `/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/` and one that checks it's not just digits `/^[^0-9]+$/` Only check the second one if the first one passes.

Answer (score 1):

This regexp should do the job: `/^[a-zA-Z\d]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*^/`

Mind you, this regex is potentially going to a significant amount of backtracking; it will be `O(N^2)` in the worst case.  Making the first repetition lazy instead of eager will make the regex faster ... if it is going to match.  The way to speed up the no-match case is to use two regexes.

Or better still, don't use regexes at all and code match in simple Java:

```
public boolean matchSymbol (String input) {
    boolean seenLetter = false;
    final int len = input.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' || ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
            seenLetter = true;
        } else if (ch < '0' || ch > '9') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return seenLetter;
}
```

For an N character String, this succeeds in `N` loop iterations or fails in (typically) less than `N` iterations.

Answer (score 0):

```
"^[0-9]*+[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*+$"
```